# sublime text not showing vertical lines from div to div

Tags: tags, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 2. I want to get vertical lines that helps me to understand where my `<div>` ends. I have attached screenshot please go through it.

Somebody please let me know how to enable vertical lines from `<div>` to `</div>`.

[image: my_screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's meant by "vertical lines" in your question.
But you can see the `</div>` on line 15 is underlined. This feature is called "close tag matching".

You can install [BracketHighlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/BracketHighlighter) to improve the highlighting of tags.